# MariaDB simple SELECT ORDER does not sort

Tags: mariadb

The SQL for MariaDB:

```
SELECT name FROM template_items ORDER BY name ASC;
```

MariaDB returns the following:

> 3.1 1 of 2
>
> h1
>
> 2.9 1 of 2

That isn't being sorted by name properly, why?

---

```
CREATE TABLE `cms_template_items` (
 `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `description` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci',
 `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci',
 `url` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci'
ENGINE=MyISAM
AUTO_INCREMENT=103;
```

> 3.1 Body id 1 of 2 / 20332E3120426F64792069642031206F662032
>
> h1 / 206831
>
> 2.9-body-id-1-of-2 / 322E392D626F64792D69642D312D6F662D32

Comment: Show us `SELECT name, HEX(name) FROM template_items ORDER BY name;` and also `SHOW CREATE TABLE template_name`.

Comment: @RickJames Updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the leading space (hex 20) on the first two lines.  Spaces sort before visible characters; digits sort before letters.

```
20 33 ...
20 68 ...
32 2E ...
```

See the `TRIM` function (in PHP or MySQL/MariaDB).  But you should probably invoke that when you insert the strings, not in `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Ah, I did notice it though only while testing some other options I came across; go figure. Thank you very much Rick!

Answer (score 1):

As you said in your answer above, the problem is that `VARCHAR` ordering is done lexicographically. It literally looks at every character and does not do natural ordering.

One way to get around this in SQL would be to separate the numeric portion of your `name` field from the rest. Ideally, you want something equivalent to this:

```
SELECT name FROM template_items ORDER BY name_numeric, name_alpha ASC;
```

Now, to get separate sections `name_numeric` and `name_alpha`, you can do something like this:

```
SELECT name FROM template_items
 ORDER BY CONVERT(LEFT(name, REGEXP_INSTR(name, '[[:blank:]]')), DECIMAL(4, 2)),
   SUBSTR(name, REGEXP_INSTR(name, '[[:blank:]]'), LENGTH(name)) ASC;
```

The idea is to first order by the numeric portion of the name on the left side of the string, and then look at everything else to the right of the first space. Note that the numeric portion is converted to DECIMAL(4,2).

The specific approach will be highly dependent on the format of your data. You may need to modify the regex a bit and you may want a `DECIMAL` value with more precision. You could also have additional groups in the `GROUP BY`, if needed.

But in the end, sorting at the application layer is easier and will be more flexible. The approach above will only work if the pattern of your data is relatively consistent.

Answer (score 0):

While user error is *usually* where the problem can be found it is *literally* a bug-by-design. The column type is `VARCHAR` and apparently MariaDB is too lazy to sort numbers, *only by letters*.

So I've removed the `ORDER BY` clause and am handling the sorting via PHP which gets the job done competently:

```
$items = array();
while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1))
{
 array_push($items,$row1['name']);
}
sort($items);
echo '<pre>'.print_r($items,1).'</pre>';
```

I've come across some other reasons:

- Some guy was connecting to the wrong database after a server transfer.
- Something about an `ENUM` type. (check your column types!)

If someone knows how to force MariaDB to properly order rows alphanumerically please feel free to post a *working answer*.

Comment: `h1` would be treated as `0` and would not sort between `3.1` and `2.9`.

Comment: `ORDER BY CONCAT('', name) ASC`.

Comment: @RickJames This works great localhost on PHP 7.2.9 though not live on 7.3.7. :-\

Comment: The version of PHP should not affect actions in MySQL??

Comment: @RickJames No, was confused between local and live server differences (the spaces were only on the live server).